# CMake: how to build external projects using Autotools?

Tags: cmake, cross-platform, autotools

I'm working on a project which uses CMake for building.
I have several external dependencies and I started using the command ExternalProject_Add to compile them. Everything works fine for the dependencies which use CMake as the build system, but I have one dependency which uses Autotools and therefore it can be compiled under Linux running

```
./configure && make && make install
```

Under Linux I managed to use ExternalProject_Add without problems.
Under Windows I found some problems:

- running configure requires a Shell
- I need to have a working make command

I managed to make the configuration step work using the bash shipped with Git but I didn't manage to make the build step work.

What is the best way to deal with this problem? How can I use ExternalProject_Add (or another cmake based method) to compile external projects based on Autotools in Windows?

Thank you

Comment: CMake's `ExternalProject` is not a magic tool which provides tools not existent in your environment. For being able to use Autotools on Windows, you need to have an environment where it works **without CMake**. E.g., it could be MinGW. After you are able to use Autotools on your system *in general*, you may try to adjust CMake's `ExternalProject_Add` for do required steps.

Comment: Note also that projects with Autotools-based build systems often have both build- and run-time dependencies outside the build system itself that are not satisfied by a typical Windows environment.  These, too, can usually be satisfied by MinGW or a similar environment, but not always.  Just because you have source does not necessarily mean that you can build or run on any particular OS.